# What is mean -- ' in mysql injection?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-injection

I am studying about mysql injection.

To complete query command, Injection code use  `-- '`.

In mysql cmd, `'' -- '` is work.

But `'' --'` is not work. It is waiting `'`

why `'' -- '` is work?

Comment: Because the SQL comment syntax is dash dash **space**. No space, not a comment.

Comment: Do you understand the basic premise of what sql injection is?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All these things has absolutely nothing to do with "injections".
That's **SQL syntax**.

`--` means comment

as it was pointed out in the comments, a space is necessary after two dashes (in mysql though. in Postgres, AFAIK, no space is required, which is a source for some unwanted behavior, like decrementing a field with negative value, `foo = foo --1`)